# WPF Binding to object created within MainWindow class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object, data-binding

So I need to bind a simple label to property of an object created from class. The Class that I am trying to create goes like this:

```
    public class Creature : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    private string _Name = "Default";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
    private string _Gender = "Default";
    public string Gender
    {
        get { return _Gender; }
        set
        {
            if (_Gender != value)
            {
                _Gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Gender));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create instance of it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs like this:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Creature Player = new Creature();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Tried setting DataContext in hopes of being able to access Player object
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Player.Gender = "Male";
        Player.Name = "Mike";
        //This bit of code here is used to check if value has changed by displaying it in a textbox
        textBox.Text = "Name: " + Player.Name;
        textBox.Text += "\nGender: " + Player.Gender;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Player.Gender = "Female";
        Player.Name = "Sarah";
        textBox.Text = "Name: " + Player.Name;
        textBox.Text += "\nGender: " + Player.Gender;
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know what is supposed to be DataContext here, as no matter what I tried I can't get access to Player field, and I tried setting it to public, didn't change anything. I still can bind to the class "Creature" but not the field, is there a way to make changes done to field Creature, apply to the class perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your class instance to the `DataContext` in your `MainWindow` constructor:

```
public Creature player;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    player = new Creature();
    this.DataContext = player;
}
```

`this` stands for current instance, so in your example it refers to class `MainWindow`

Comment: I didn't actually think of that, and it does look like it'd work. But what if I needed to assign other values, say of other objects? Can I somehow, say, set it to DataContext of a WPF control instead, like a textbox? Edit: Also the other issue would be I need to initialize the "player" field inside the class, or I won't be able to modify it's properties using button.Click functions

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to set control there. Anyway, if you want to combine view models check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781863/can-a-view-have-two-view-models-as-its-data-context)

Comment: Well it's more of being able to change the values like Name and Gender in run-time by using button functions. If it wasn't for that fact, I wouldn't bother with creating that instance in the first place

Comment: Since you've already implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `Creature` class, all you have to do is bind value in your view. For example bind it to the label: `<Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>`. And then on click button event change the value of `Name` property and it will be updated.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, but thanks for your explanation because now I know I can just set-up DataContext inside code directly to newly created field instances. Also just to note, you should set DataContext of WPF controls directly to objects that will use those controls for efficiency